# ng-class for only every element after the first 5 of an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way to use ng-class for only every element after the first 5 of an ng-repeat?

This is how it is done only for the last element.

```
  <div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="{'last':$last}">
    {{file.name}}
  </div>
```

However, I only want to add the class "hidden-md" to only every element after the first 5.

```
  <div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="{'hidden-md':$addClassToAllAfterFirst5}">
    {{file.name}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check `$index` and assign the class according to relevant condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files" ng-class="{'hidden-md':$index > 4}">
    {{file.name}}
 </div>
```